# Angular2 & Firebase - Set the current user id as the name of a node in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**What I'm doing**

I'm performing a multipath update that updates items to multiple nodes in the name of denormalised data

**Question**

Is it possible to set the current user id as a name in firebase?

For example, this would be the expected firebase node structure after an update:

- users

  - product key

    - userID: true;

The approach below works fine for other pieces of data and others nodes because I'm specifying the node name, such as

> title: title,

However, when trying to get the user uid, it won't accept a variable due to the '.' (var userId = user.uid and then this.userId: true)

**the part that says 'user:true' is where I would like to specify the user id: true**

```js
submitForm(title: string, reference: string, date: string, auditorName: string, newCompanyName: string) {
    this.authService.user.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
      


        var userList = {
          user: true
        }



        var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('product_list').push().key;
        
        var updates = {};

        updates['/users/' + newPostKey] = userList;

        return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

      }

    });

  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just figured it out.    var userList = {
          [userId]:true
        }

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.

```
Var userID = user.uid
var userList = {
     [userId]:true 
}
```